# How to modify Hibernate generated SQL when lazily loading association in Grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have three tables with the following associations in an Oracle database:

Company, User, Settings
One Company has many Users
One User has many Settings
Settings has a foreign key referencing a Company (in other words, one Company has many Settings)
The Settings table is partitioned by Company and has an index on the User.

I am trying to have Hibernate generate a query to lazily load the settings for a user, while taking advantage of the partition by including the Company in the query. Currently, writing the following Grails code:

```
def settings = user.settings
```

results in the following (simplified) query:

```
SELECT * FROM SETTINGS WHERE USER_ID=user.id
```

I'd like the following query to be generated instead when calling the Grails code above:

```
SELECT * FROM SETTINGS WHERE USER_ID=user.id AND COMPANY_ID=company.id
```

Also, from my understanding, after the collection is lazily loaded, the concrete, initialized collection is then attached to the associated object and further calls to that collection then retrieve the collection from memory, rather than run another query. This is important as I will be calling user.settings multiple times in different process flows, so I am looking for a solution that will do the same.

Is it possible to do so without any significant changes to the source code?

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you're looking for with a GORM query. I'm going to assume `Setting` does not `belongsTo` `User`, which complicates things a bit. In this case the best fit is HQL.

```
def settings = Setting.executeQuery 'select s from User as u inner join u.settings as s inner join s.company as c where u = :user and c = :company', [user: someUser, company: someCompany]
```

## With a reference to User

If `Setting` does have a back-reference to `User`, then you can use a simple criteria or where query.

### Criteria

```
def settings = Setting.withCriteria {
    eq 'user', someUser
    eq 'company', someCompany
}
```

### Where

```
def settings = Setting.where {
    user == someUser
    company == someCompany
}
```

### HQL

What the heck, here's the equivalent HQL.

```
def settings = Setting.findAll 'from Setting where user = :user and company = :company', [user: someUser, company: someCompany]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, you are correct in that Setting has a back-reference to User. However, here's where it gets more complicated (just added this to the edit) - in the context of my app, user.settings is accessed multiple times in a process. I've tried overriding the accessor to utilize the more optimized query as well as try to store the results into the Settings variable on the User, but it's not playing so nice. Happen to have any ideas on this?

Comment: If  you're passing the same `User` around, and various functions are accessing _it's_ `.settings`, you may be able to create a `User` decorator with a `getSettings()` method that returns the cached settings. Then pass the decorated `User` to avoid the database hit. http://www.groovy-lang.org/design-patterns.html#_decorator_pattern

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to append a filter in hibernate query in which company id conditions gets appended automatically.

For this you can use grails hibernate filter plugin. I used this plugin about 4 years ago not sure how it works now https://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter